# Deploying a WAR with Jackson dependencies with scope 'compile' to WILDFLY

Tags: wildfly

As you may know, WILDFLY already provides `jackson` as modules so applications that are deployed to a WILDFLY server do not need to include jackson as a ompile dependency. Normally, such applications should use the `provided` scope for jackson dependencies in that case.

I'm wondering what happens when I deploy a WAR to WILDFLY which has `jackson` dependencies in `compile` scope. Which Jackson will be used inside the WILDFLY Container? The ones provided by WILDFLY or the ones provided by the application JAR? Or is it completely random?

Comment: It somewhat depends. For things in your deployment, it would likely be the Jackson library from your deployment. For modules add, e.g. the Jackson provider for RESTEasy, it would be the Jackson module.